# How can I cut too wide image in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I want to set same height of image always and cut image sides to page width - how can I achieve it :)

```
    +- Page ----+
    |           |
+---+- Image ---+---+
|   |           |   |
|   |           |   |
|   |           |   |
+---+-----------+---+
    |           |
    +-----------+
```

I want strip this image with css to this.

```
    +- Page ----+
    |           |
    +- Image ---+
    |           |
    |           |
    |           |
    +-----------+
    |           |
    +-----------+
```

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to ensure an image-width always corresponds to the page-width (or to the width of the parent element which contains it) is:

```
img {
width: 100%;
}
```

If you wanted the same image to always have a consistent height, then you would follow the relative-to-parent width with a unit-based height, like this:

```
img {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
```

If it's important for you to maintain the image's height-width ratio (and, consequently, you don't mind losing the sides of the image), then use:

```
img {
height: 200px;
margin: 12px auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how to do it with an img tag:

```css
.img-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img-wrap div {
  margin: 0 -1000px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrap">
  <div>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/1920x1280">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll use one of two methods: first, make overflow of the body element hidden, then nest the image within an element whose width is larger than the page and then apply to that element the following style definition:

```
margin:auto;
```

Second, and this is just for display purposes, you can set the image as the background of the page or an element as large as the page and then,

```
background-size:cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to know how to center an image in the background without it being affected by browser viewport width or height changes.

You can use the following CSS:

`body { 
    background: url(/path/to/img.png) center center no-repeat fixed;
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image to fit screen in horizontal, use this:

```
img {
width: 100%;
}
```

If you want your image to always in the center of page add this

```
img {
position: absolute;
top: 25%; //edit this to make your image farther from top of screen
}
```

**Note:** This only work well if parent element of your img is body (or something that width and height are equal 100% of screen)